# jquery event doesnt work

Tags: jquery

```
<form id='new_key' action='/foo/bar' method='post'>
    <input type="text" id="u">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I can bind a jQuery event to this element like:

```
$('#new_key').ready(function () {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
});
```

It works as expected, but if I do:

```
$('#new_key').submit(function () {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
});
```

it doesn't work. Does anybody know why? What am I missing?

Comment: Does it give any error? If yes, then what is the error? //or, you can wrap the function, withind $(document).ready(function(){});
//This is already asnwered by strager

Comment: do you have JavaScript enabled in your browser?

Comment: if the ready works, how should it be disabled? -1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in a `$(function() { })` block:

```
$(function() {
  $('#new_key').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: i surround it by a function but then i must bind this function with a event right? maybe the $(document).ready ?

Comment: `$(function() { X; });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { X; });`.

Answer (score 5):

Your form tag ID should just be declared as `new_key`, not `#new_key`:

```
<form id='new_key' action='/foo/bar' method='post'>
```

The `#` is not part of the ID, it's a signal to jQuery to match an element by it's ID, based on `#`'s usage in CSS.

Comment: i was sleeping. the new id in the form declaration dont have it. it was a mistake

Answer (score 2):

`$.fn.ready` executes when the DOM is ready.  It doesn't look at the jQuery object.  So, your `'#new_key'` part is being ignored.

As [Tobias Cohen answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386048/jquery-event-dont-works/2386075#2386075), the ID of your form element needs to be changed by removing the preceding `#`.

Comment: i was sleeping. the new id in the form declaration dont have it. it was a mistake